# Need help with gate lock

Tags: fence, gates

[image]We had a chain link gate custom ordered by an installer that ended up being incorrectly sized and the installer has vanished. 1 and 1/4 gate pole and 2 and 3/8 post are the dimensions, however, there isn’t enough clearance for the lock to fit. Anyone have any suggestions on a size for this or maybe an alternative lock?

Comment: What's the other side look like? It's usually possible to rotate the hinges where the gate attaches to the rest of the fence to get yourself enough distance to fix this problem. If you can add a picture of how the gate is attached to the fence I can confirm that.

Comment: There are lots of other fate latch designs, some if which take less space. Go shopping.

Comment: Yeah, except they all suck except that kind. Spin the hinges a bit and mount that thing at a slight angle.

Comment: With this kind of workmanship, it's not surprising that the installer vanished. Sorry about that...

Comment: Would probably require a professional, but one possible solution could be to simply cut, shorten, and re-weld the top and bottom pipes.